# Do I need a prescription to bring medication into Japan that is prescription-only there but OTC in the US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan

I am going to Japan for a week-and-a-half trip (leaving from the US). I often take Melatonin to help myself sleep, and especially want it to help with jetlag (in both directions). It is available over-the-counter here in the US, but as I understand requires a prescription in Japan.

As far as I can tell, Japan allows visitors to bring up to a 2 month supply of non-prescription medicine, and up to a 1 month supply of prescription medicine for personal use (except Narcotics and Psychotropics which are banned). [In their FAQ](https://www.mhlw.go.jp/english/policy/health-medical/pharmaceuticals/dl/qa2.pdf) (see Q1), they don't say you need a prescription to bring prescription medication, just that it must be <1 month supply for personal use and not in certain restricted categories. I don't have a prescription for the melatonin as that is not needed in the US.

Do I need a prescription to bring it with me to Japan?

Comment: I can't answer for Japan specifically, but for other countries they want a Dr letter saying why you need it -- I did this for Sudafed which is more regulated in other places than it is at home.

Answer (score 2):

Submit an application for "Yunyu Kakunin-sho", as specified in the document you linked. You may try applying without a prescription and explain it is an OTC drug - the reviewer may ask you to provide one but if you could convince them then it wouldn't be an issue.

As stated in the [official documents dated June 2023](https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/001122409.pdf), individuals and doctors living in Japan need to apply for an import permit to get Melatonin.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm leaving for japan today and so won't have time for them to get back to me :(

Answer (score 2):

In practice no one cares about melatonin. In Japan, there are countless services that help local residents purchase melatonin abroad and get them shipped to Japan; people use it all the time, I have used it, and no one's ever said anything. As long as the quantity is clearly for personal use, nothing could happen.